# Flow formula wrongly evaluates to false

Tags: visual-workflow

I am trying to add below code to entry criteria in a flow.
It evaluates to false even though the `Status_vod__c` is Approved_vod and prior status is closed.

The scenario is there is an unlock button on the Event object which when clicked, the status is changed from closed to approved.

```
AND(
    OR(
        ISPICKVAL({!$Record.Status_vod__c}, 'Approved_vod'),
        ISPICKVAL({!$Record.Status_vod__c}, 'PG_ApprovedWithAttendees'),
        ISPICKVAL({!$Record.Status_vod__c}, 'Requested_vod')
    ),
    ISPICKVAL({!$Record__Prior.Status_vod__c}, 'Closed_vod')
)
```

Comment: prior status is 'closed' or prior status is 'Closed_vod'?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the `Status_vod__c` field you have used has `Approved_vod, PG_ApprovedWithAttendees, Requested_vod` values. Also, this is the API Name of the value, not a Label.

As I have validated the below entry criteria in my org and it is working fine. I have used the Case object status field.

**Entry Criteria:**

```
AND( 
    OR( 
        ISPICKVAL({!$Record.Status}, "Open"),
        ISPICKVAL({!$Record.Status}, "Working")
    ),
    ISPICKVAL({!$Record__Prior.Status}, "Closed")
)
```

**Your Entry Criteria:**

```
AND(
    ISCHANGED({!$Record.Status_vod__c}), 
    OR( 
        ISPICKVAL({!$Record.Status_vod__c}, "Approved_vod"),
        ISPICKVAL({!$Record.Status_vod__c}, "PG_ApprovedWithAttendees"),
        ISPICKVAL({!$Record.Status_vod__c}, "Requested_vod")
    ),
    ISPICKVAL({!$Record__Prior.Status_vod__c}, "Closed_vod")
)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your input, however for some reason !$Record__Prior.Status_vod__c is not taking the prior value, it is giving the current value.

Also i am facing this error 'the record is ready to be updated when the interview finishes.'  in debug after update

Please let me know if you have any idea

Comment: I have edited the Entry criteria. So whenever the Status_vod__c field is changed 
 and Status_vod__c field contains any of the values Approved_vod, PG_ApprovedWithAttendees, Requested_vod and the prior value of this field is Closed_vod then only the flow run.